# WaitForSeconds не работает

Tags: c#, unity3d

создаю игру на основе тетриса для чего нужна coroutina но функция WaitForSeconds проигрывается слишком быстро

```
void Update () {
    StartCoroutine(GenerateFigure());
}

IEnumerator GenerateFigure () {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    Instantiate(
        Generate(), //функция которая выдаёт рандомную фигуру
        new Vector3(0f, 3f, 0f),
        Quaternion.identity
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй изменить свой код так. Должно получиться то, что ты хочешь

```
private void Start() 
{
    StartCoroutine(GenerateFigure());
}

private IEnumerator GenerateFigure() 
{
    while(true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        Instantiate(
            Generate(), //функция которая выдаёт рандомную фигуру
            new Vector3(0f, 3f, 0f),
            Quaternion.identity
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как по мне проще использовать метод Invoke()

Так как используемому варианту я не очень доверяю, а через Invoke() гораздо проще.
Нужно просто запихнуть необходимую команду(ы) в функцию и выполнить её через этот метод. (p.s. Я сам использую данный метод)

В вашем случае

```
void ObjGenerate() {
   Instantiate(
        Generate(), //функция которая выдаёт рандомную фигуру
        new Vector3(0f, 3f, 0f),
        Quaternion.identity
   );
}

void Update () {
    StartCoroutine(GenerateFigure());
}

IEnumerator GenerateFigure () {
    Invoke("ObjGenerate", 2f); //первое значение это функция которая выполнится, а второе значение это задержка в секундах
}
```

Надеюсь помог

Comment: В вашем случае, наверное, стоило бы еще написать чем данный вариант предпочтительнее и в чем недостатки примера предоставленного автором вопроса

Comment: Не вижу смысла в корутине, внутри которой один единственный вызов и ни одного yield